# Can I use "afford" as a meaning of job ability?

Tags: vocabulary

I have a job interview next week and I am writing a script because I am not a native speaker of English.
And now, I'd like to ask if I can use the word afford as in the following.

> I afford to perform this job with my both abilities

Comment: Short answer: no.  "Afford" does not mean "am able to", except in the sense of "am able to pay for something."  Yes, there is a sense in which it means "to provide or supply", but that's a tricky usage that I would not recommend to a new learner.

Answer (score 2):

That just sounds awkward, both grammatically and semantically. *afford* is definitely not going to work here. It's better to say something like this:

> I can assure you that I'm going to do this job to the best of my abilities.

Answer (score 1):

Afford sounds a bit weird to me as well.. I would write it as:

> You can be assured that I will perform to the best of my abilities.

Or

> I aim to complete this job to the best of my abilities.

Or

> I will be aiming to perform to the best of my ability, so that I may provide the best results possible at this job.

Answer (score 0):

Afford: to be ​able to ​buy or do something because you have enough ​money or ​time.
from cambridage lerners dictionary.

Afford emphasises on the time or money matters. so you can not use afford.